# Redirect match string hostname to an ip address using iptables

Tags: iptables

I want to redirect every hostname that have `.org` name inside it, like `example.org`,`example2.org`,`notexample.org` to an ip address (for an example 127.0.0.1)

I tried using this command

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m string --algo bm --string ".org" -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

But it doesn't work
How to solve it?

Edit: there's another solution i found but it's only for redirecting hostname to ip address not matched string to ip address

Here's the command :

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d example.org -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Iptables is not the tool for the job. You may want to look at intercepting DNS requests....

Comment: @davidgo how to?

Comment: Set up a DNS server which provides an answer with the desired IP for the zones you want but otherwise vacating as an authorarive/recursive name server (presumably using named/bind or dnsmasq). Then use an iptables rule to intercept all traffic leaving your network (except for your name server) and redirect it to your name server using an iptables DNAT rules in the PREROUTIG chain. If you Google "iptables intercept dns" you should find the help you need.